# Display the discounted percentage near sale price in Single product pages for WC 3.0+

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, discount

I had this code in `function.php` of my theme to display the percentage after price and it was working fine in WooCommerce v2.6.14.

But this snippet doesn't work anymore on WooCommerce version 3.0+.

How can I fix that?

Here is that code:

```
// Add save percent next to sale item prices.
add_filter( 'woocommerce_sale_price_html', 'woocommerce_custom_sales_price', 10, 2 );
function woocommerce_custom_sales_price( $price, $product ) {
    $percentage = round( ( ( $product->regular_price - $product->sale_price ) / $product->regular_price ) * 100 );
    return $price . sprintf( __(' Save %s', 'woocommerce' ), $percentage . '%' );
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> **Updated** - 2019 *(avoid rounding price issue)* - 2017 *(avoid `NAN%` percentage value)*

**`woocommerce_sale_price_html`** hook has been replaced by a different hook in WooCommerce 3.0+, that has now 3 arguments (but not the **`$product`** argument anymore).

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_format_sale_price', 'woocommerce_custom_sales_price', 10, 3 );
function woocommerce_custom_sales_price( $price, $regular_price, $sale_price ) {
    // Getting the clean numeric prices (without html and currency)
    $_reg_price = floatval( strip_tags($regular_price) );
    $_sale_price = floatval( strip_tags($sale_price) );

    // Percentage calculation and text
    $percentage = round( ( $_reg_price - $_sale_price ) / $_reg_price * 100 ).'%';
    $percentage_txt = ' ' . __(' Save ', 'woocommerce' ) . $percentage;

    $formatted_regular_price = is_numeric( $regular_price ) ? wc_price( $regular_price ) : $regular_price;
    $formatted_sale_price    = is_numeric( $sale_price )    ? wc_price( $sale_price )    : $sale_price;

    echo '<del>' . $formatted_regular_price . '</del> <ins>' . $formatted_sale_price . $percentage_txt . '</ins>';
}
```

This code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.
 The code is tested and works. For WooCommerce version 3.0+ *(thanks to @Mikebcn and @AsifRao)*

For rounding the percentage you can use [`round()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.round.php), [`number_format()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) or [`number_format_i18n()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/number_format_i18n/):

```
$percentage = number_format_i18n( ( $_reg_price - $_sale_price ) / $_reg_price * 100, 0 ).'%';

$percentage = number_format( ( $_reg_price - $_sale_price ) / $_reg_price * 100, 0 ).'%';
```

---

**Original answer code:** Here is that functional similar code:

```
// Only for WooCommerce version 3.0+
add_filter( 'woocommerce_format_sale_price', 'woocommerce_custom_sales_price', 10, 3 );
function woocommerce_custom_sales_price( $price, $regular_price, $sale_price ) {
    $percentage = round( ( $regular_price - $sale_price ) / $regular_price * 100 ).'%';
    $percentage_txt = ' ' . __(' Save ', 'woocommerce' ) . $percentage;
    $price = '<del>' . ( is_numeric( $regular_price ) ? wc_price( $regular_price ) : $regular_price ) . '</del> <ins>' . ( is_numeric( $sale_price ) ? wc_price( $sale_price ) . $percentage_txt : $sale_price . $percentage_txt ) . '</ins>';
    return $price;
}
```

This code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.
 The code is tested and works. For WooCommerce version 3.0+.

Comment: its returning NAN%

Comment: @LoicTheAztec in my case $regular_price returrning "<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">65.99<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span></span>" not just the regular price but all this html and thats why it is returning nan

Comment: @LoicTheAztec realised it's WooCommerce's Measurement Price Calculator that alters the price. Having to edit the plugin's files manually and save it in a different name :(

Comment: @LoicTheAztec theres no hook, just a function in the plugin that changes the price displayed. says in the plugin documentation that there are major conflicts with anything changing the price also

Comment: This does not work with variation product apparently.