# Display lowest variation price and discounted percentage in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, price

Based on this post :

- [Displaying the lowest variation price of variable products](https://businessbloomer.com/disable-variable-product-price-range-woocommerce/) 
  And this topic :
- [Display the discounted percentage near sale price in Single product pages for WC 3.0+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43757920/display-the-discounted-percentage-near-sale-price-in-single-product-pages-for-wc)

I've been trying to show everywhere on my website the lowest variation price with the associated discount %, for variable and non variable products.

Here is the current code that I am using:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variable_price_html', 'bbloomer_variation_price_format', 10, 2 );


function bbloomer_variation_price_format( $price, $product ) {

    // Main Price
    $prices = array( $product->get_variation_price( 'min', true ), $product->get_variation_price( 'max', true ) );
    $price = $prices[0] !== $prices[1] ? sprintf( __( '%1$s', 'woocommerce' ), wc_price( $prices[0] ) ) : wc_price( $prices[0] );

    // Sale Price
    $prices = array( $product->get_variation_regular_price( 'min', true ), $product->get_variation_regular_price( 'max', true ) );
    sort( $prices );
    $saleprice = $prices[0] !== $prices[1] ? sprintf( __( '%1$s', 'woocommerce' ), wc_price( $prices[0] ) ) : wc_price( $prices[0] );

    if ( $price !== $saleprice ) {
        $price = '<del>' . $saleprice . '</del> <ins>' . $price . '</ins>';
    }
    return $price;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_format_sale_price', 'woocommerce_custom_sales_price', 10, 3 );
function woocommerce_custom_sales_price( $price, $regular_price, $sale_price ) {
    // Getting the clean numeric prices (without html and currency)
    $regular_price = floatval( strip_tags($regular_price) );
    $sale_price = floatval( strip_tags($sale_price) );

    // Percentage calculation and text
    $percentage = round( ( $regular_price - $sale_price ) / $regular_price * 100 ).'%';
    $percentage_txt = __(' Save ', 'woocommerce' ).$percentage;

    return '<del>' . wc_price( $regular_price ) . '</del> <ins>' . wc_price( $sale_price ) . $percentage_txt . '</ins>';
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_dropdown_variation_attribute_options_args', 'mmx_remove_select_text');
```

If I only keep the second function, it works on every product but not on variable products, which show a price range on shop pages. If I add the first function, it shows instead of a price range the price of the lowest product variation, but without the discount % next to it.

I could add the % code of the second function to the first, but this is messy, is there a way to merge these functions so that I can have the discount % shown everywhere, and also next to the lowest variation when it's a variable product?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done changing a little bit the first function that will replace both hooked functions:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'custom_price_format', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variable_price_html', 'custom_price_format', 10, 2 );
function custom_price_format( $price, $product ) {

    // Main Price
    $regular_price = $product->is_type('variable') ? $product->get_variation_regular_price( 'min', true ) : $product->get_regular_price();
    $sale_price = $product->is_type('variable') ? $product->get_variation_sale_price( 'min', true ) : $product->get_sale_price();


    if ( $regular_price !== $sale_price && $product->is_on_sale()) {
        // Percentage calculation and text
        $percentage = round( ( $regular_price - $sale_price ) / $regular_price * 100 ).'%';
        $percentage_txt = __(' Save', 'woocommerce' ).' '.$percentage;

        $price = '<del>' . wc_price($regular_price) . '</del> <ins>' . wc_price($sale_price) . $percentage_txt . '</ins>';
    }
    return $price;
}
```

This code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme).

Tested and works with your customizations made in your previous questions/answer.

Comment: @malcom. Can you mark the post as answered? That would help for in the future when others might be looking for help with the issue. Just a suggestion, not a command! :-)

Comment: There is a delay to be able to validate an answer, it's now marked as done !