# PHP function output only updates after click on page

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce, price

So I was looking for a way to update Pricing for a variable Product (Woocommerce + WP), without showing the Price Range + Final Price (including Variables).

I stumbled upon this script, which seems to work perfectly for my use case. [Source - Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44912300/replace-the-variable-price-range-by-the-chosen-variation-price-in-woocommerce-3)

It works fine on mobile.
However, in Desktop Browser, it requires me to click on a random place of the page to update the pricing. This is very inconvenient.
Any idea how to fix this?

My coding skills are limited to HTML/CSS and very basic js.
Any help is appreciated.

This is the code:

```
   add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product', 'check_if_variable_first' );
function check_if_variable_first(){
   if ( is_product() ) {
       global $post;
       $product = wc_get_product( $post->ID );
       if ( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {
           // removing the price of variable products
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10 );

// Change location of
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'custom_wc_template_single_price', 10 );
function custom_wc_template_single_price(){
   global $product;

// Variable product only
if($product->is_type('variable')):

   // Main Price
   $prices = array( $product->get_variation_price( 'min', true ), $product->get_variation_price( 'max', true ) );
   $price = $prices[0] !== $prices[1] ? sprintf( __( 'From: %1$s', 'woocommerce' ), wc_price( $prices[0] ) ) : wc_price( $prices[0] );

   // Sale Price
   $prices = array( $product->get_variation_regular_price( 'min', true ), $product->get_variation_regular_price( 'max', true ) );
   sort( $prices );
   $saleprice = $prices[0] !== $prices[1] ? sprintf( __( 'From: %1$s', 'woocommerce' ), wc_price( $prices[0] ) ) : wc_price( $prices[0] );

   if ( $price !== $saleprice && $product->is_on_sale() ) {
       $price = '<del>' . $saleprice . $product->get_price_suffix() . '</del> <ins>' . $price . $product->get_price_suffix() . '</ins>';
   }

   ?>
   <style>
       div.woocommerce-variation-price,
       div.woocommerce-variation-availability,
       div.hidden-variable-price {
           height: 0px !important;
           overflow:hidden;
           position:relative;
           line-height: 0px !important;
           font-size: 0% !important;
       }
   </style>
   <script>
   jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
       $('select').blur( function(){
           if( '' != $('input.variation_id').val() ){
               $('p.price').html($('div.woocommerce-variation-price > span.price').html()).append('<p class="availability">'+$('div.woocommerce-variation-availability').html()+'</p>');
               console.log($('input.variation_id').val());
           } else {
               $('p.price').html($('div.hidden-variable-price').html());
               if($('p.availability'))
                   $('p.availability').remove();
               console.log('NULL');
           }
       });
   });
   </script>
   <?php

   echo '<p class="price">'.$price.'</p>
   <div class="hidden-variable-price" >'.$price.'</div>';

endif;
}

       }
   }
}
```

[LINK to Image for Usecase explanation - See also Stackoverflow Link where I took the code from](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1KVpj.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem which you are facing seems to be the `$('select').blur()`.
As you want this to change automatically, I suggest changing this to change()..

```
   <script>
   jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
       $('select').change( function(){
           if( '' != $('input.variation_id').val() ){
               $('p.price').html($('div.woocommerce-variation-price > span.price').html()).append('<p class="availability">'+$('div.woocommerce-variation-availability').html()+'</p>');
               console.log($('input.variation_id').val());
           } else {
               $('p.price').html($('div.hidden-variable-price').html());
               if($('p.availability'))
                   $('p.availability').remove();
               console.log('NULL');
           }
       });
   });
   </script>
```

The `blur()` event occurs when an object loses focus.. In your case, when you click off the screen.

the `change()` event occurs when the object changes.. In your case, whenever the select option changes

Comment: Thank you. Learned a lot. This fixed the problem, while showing other errors with the code in general. Output added "undefined" whenever a variable didn't influence the final price. Final Solution for the Problem in general was found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50704727/replace-the-variable-price-range-by-the-chosen-variation-price-in-woocommerce-4/50707820#50707820

Answer (score 0):

The code above was flawed.
I found a better solution for my use case in this post: [Update Woo Variable Price](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50704727/replace-the-variable-price-range-by-the-chosen-variation-price-in-woocommerce-4/50707820#50707820)