# Show variable product price according to taxonomy page in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am working on a shop where I sell variable products.

Each product has 1 global attribute with 3-5 terms used as variants also. I used [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50681539/display-default-variation-price-for-variable-products-in-woocommerce-shop-pages) to show the default variant price on shop page and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44912300/replace-the-variable-price-range-by-the-chosen-variation-price-in-woocommerce-3) to change the price according to the selected variant on product page.

**Attribute: Condition |
Terms: Ver1, Ver2, Ver3, Ver4, Ver5.**

I have an archive page which can be accesed on **localhost/condition/ver1** and show only the products with ver1 variant.

I would like:

1. When I go to the above page to display the price of that variant (Ver1) for all products.
2. When I click on a product from this page, take me to the product page with Ver1 like default variant selected.

I think this problems can be solved with **term_link()** but I'm not sure how to do it. Thank you!